# Reading Wav Files, wrong output

Tags: c++, matlab, wav

I have posted a simular problem before (Thought it would be better to start a fresh and hopefully, get more opinions on it). Basically, the problem is that I am trying to read the data from a .wav file, however, the output is different to that of what it is in MatLab.

In C++ the output is:

-128

Whereas in Matlab:

0

The output is completely different, not just small differences, but the whole dataset is wrong and I don't seem to know why. I think it might have something to do with endianness but, I am not sure. Here is the header information about the .wav file:

```
**** WAV FILE *****
Chunk IDRIFFN?
Chunk Size: 57934
Format: WAVEfmt 
Format: IDfmt 
FormatSize: 18
Format2: 1
Channel Num: 1
Sample Rate: 22050
Byte Rate: 22050
Align: 1
Bits Per Sample: 8
```

And the code:

```
file.read(this->chunkId,                                 4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->chunkSize),     4);
file.read(this->format,                                  4);

file.read(this->formatId,                                4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->formatSize),    4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->format2),       2);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->numChannels),   2);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->sampleRate),    4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->byteRate),      4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->align),         2);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->bitsPerSample), 4);

char testing[4] = {0};
int testingSize = 0;

while(file.read(testing, 4) && (testing[0] != 'd' ||
                                testing[1] != 'a' ||
                                testing[2] != 't' ||
                                testing[3] != 'a'))
{

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&testingSize), 4);
    file.seekg(testingSize, std::ios_base::cur);

}

this->dataId[0] = testing[0];
this->dataId[1] = testing[1];
this->dataId[2] = testing[2];
this->dataId[3] = testing[3];



file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->dataSize),     4);

this->data = new char[this->dataSize];

file.read(data,this->dataSize);

cout << "**** WAV FILE *****" << endl;
cout << "Chunk ID" << this->chunkId << endl;
cout << "Chunk Size" << this->chunkSize << endl;
cout << "Format: " << this->format << endl;
cout << "Format ID" << this->formatId << endl;
cout << "FormatSize" << this->formatSize << endl;
cout << "Format2 " << this->format2 << endl;
cout << "Channel Num" << this->numChannels << endl;
cout << "Sample Rate" << this->sampleRate << endl;
cout << "Byte Rate" << this->byteRate << endl;
cout << "Align" << this->align << endl;
cout << "Bits Per Sample" << this->bitsPerSample << endl;
cout << "Size" << testingSize << endl;



for(unsigned i=0; (i < 20); i++){
    cout << (float) data[i] << endl;
}

return true;
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I have tried to debug it, but, had no joy (I'm using g++ to compile). Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Sorry I keep asking this, it's really annoying me now!

Thanks

Comment: The best thing would be to put the wav file you are trying to read on some web-site then people can try your code against the file. BTW there is no output in the code you've posted. So when you say the output should be 0, what output are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry didn't scroll down so I missed the output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe chunks in a WAV file must be aligned to the nearest WORD boundary. If after the format section that you've parsed your not at the next word boundary, you wont enter the while loop and your code will assume that youre at the data section.

Similarly, if any of your chunks are an odd number of bytes long, you might run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

OK looking at the code it looks like a casting error. You are clearly trying to output twenty floats (made up of four bytes each) but what you actually output is just twenty bytes, each single byte converted to a single float. I think you might want this

```
for(unsigned i=0; (i < 20); i++){
    cout << ((float*) data)[i] << endl;
}
```

In other words you convert data to a float pointer and then apply the index. Not apply the index first and then convert to a float.

Comment: thank you for your reply. That didn't seem to work, I get "-1.1801e-38" values instead of 0 now..

Comment: @Phorce Well I think my version is closer to correct, but there are so many ways this can go wrong that it's hard to speculate what the correct answer is. It could be an endianness issue with the floats for instance. But it could be many other things. You need to make the file you are using available to others somehow. Put it on pastebin for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the audio file can be found at: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~dwagn/aiproj/craigyes.wav - Please let me know how you got on :)! Any help would be greatful!

Comment: @Phorce: OK bad news I'm afraid. Firstly now I understand a little more about the WAV format my suggestion was completely wrong. The correct loop is very similar to yours, it should be `for (unsigned i = 0; i < 20; i++) { cout << (unsigned)(unsigned char)data[i] << endl; }`. With this change the output will be 128 128 128 ... . Now for the bad news, there are no bugs in your code, this is the correct sample output according to the code and the WAV file. The question is, why do you think Matlab is right to output zero? Some background explanation is needed I think.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. Basically, I'm using the guy's coding (in matlab) to guide me through the process. The MatLab code does basically this: rawdata = wavread('file'); which SHOULD output the correct information.. Am I missing something?

Comment: OK I'm just reading the MatLab documentation here http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/wavread.html. I know little about MatLab. But I'm looking at the format parameter which has two options 'native' and 'double', 'double' is the default. Looking at the tables below I see that if double format is used and N < 32 (as in your case) then the range of values produced is -1 to +1. So I think matlab has normalized the values it has read, from a range of 0 to 255, to a range of -1.0 to 1.0. I think you should try and use the 'native' option. See if that gives you the same values as your C++.

Comment: @Phorce Unfortunately I don't know enough about MatLab to know how to do that, maybe `rawdata = wavread('file', 'native')`?

Comment: Ohhh, so I need to normalise the data? haha! So if it's < 128 it's 0 etc.. If that was the case, why would matlab print results like: 0.0078, 0.0156, 0.0078 further down the output.. This is weird! Thank you so much for your replies though :)!

Comment: just tried the 'native' in matlab, i'm getting the same results as I'm getting in C++ :D! I just need to normalise the data.. But, that's a strange thing considering I'm getting: 0.0078, 0.0156
0.0078 when not doing native

Comment: @Phorce Well I think that clinches it 1/128 = 0.0078, 2/128 = 0.0156 etc.

Comment: I don't get how the data should be normalised.. Sorry ahah!

Comment: @Phorce `for (unsigned i = 0; i < 20; i++) { unsigned char b = data[i]; cout << (b - 128)/128.0 << endl; }` I think.

Comment: aha no no "-2" thank you though, I'll do some reading. I might be able to get around without normalising the data..

Answer (score 0):

I think in matlab value are normalised in between -1 to 1, so in order to get the similar output in c++ you need to scale them.
Example for the samples that are 16-bit in the range of -32768 to 32767 and you want them scaled to -1.0 to 1.0. The way to do this is to divide by 32768.0 (-32768/32768.0 == -1, 32767/32768.0 is slightly less than 1).

```
for(unsigned i=0; (i < 20); i++){
    cout << ((float) data[i])/32768.0 << endl;
}
```